# How to avoid delay of adjusting the screen size during Orientation change of android Activity

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have an activity with the fallowing property in manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

While doing orientation change screen size adjustment is delaying some times.

Suppose if I am trying to config from Portrait to landscape

The screen showing portrait only after some time (2 to 3 secs) the screen getting resize to landscape. even same thing happening for Landscape to portrait also.

The above delay is making some confusion to the user.
So kindly please suggest any solution/suggestions to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you specify "orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize" in configChanges it means that the action to be performed when there is a change in the above mentioned properties when a activity is in foreground has been handled in the activity itself (using the onConfigurationChanged())

There may be some tedious task ie being performed in the activity's onConfigurationChanged() of your activity which is resulting in the delay. If not the device may be slow and is takes time to change orientation

Comment: Thank you, for the valuable suggession. did you face this problem so far?

Answer (score 0):

Your view gets remeasured and rebuilt from scratch, if the layout is complex that's the time it takes.